# How to calculate 95% confidence intervals using bayesboot()

Tags: r, logistic-regression, bayesian, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I need help to calculate [bootstrap-based](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ss/1032280214) [credible intervals](https://github.com/rasmusab/bayesboot) of the quantity `qtt.ci` from my regression `coef.def`.

So far my attempts have resulted in:

> Error in quantile.default(s, c(0.025, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.975)) : 
>   missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE

preceded by:

> Warning message: In bayesboot(dat, boot_fn) :   The sample from
>   bayesboot contains either NAs, NaNs or NULLs. Make sure that your
>   statistic function only return actual values.

Here are my sample data:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 1, 0, 0), B = c(1, 0, 1, 0),
  Pass = c(278, 100, 153, 79), Fail = c(743, 581, 1232, 1731)
```

Below is my regression. The quantity I want to get the bootstrap-based 95% credible intervals is `qtt.ci`:

```
boot_fn <- function(dat) {
           coef.def = unname(coef(glm(cbind(Pass, Fail) ~ A * B, binomial, 
           dat)))
                          }
qtt.ci <- exp(sum(coef.def[2:4])) - exp(coef.def[2]) - exp(coef.def[3]) + 1
```

Here is my attempt:

```
bb_ci <- bayesboot(dat, boot_fn)
summary(bb_ci)
```

Not certain how to get the bootstrap-based confidence intervals for `qtt.ci`.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

**Following the answer by @RuiBarradas, I tried doing bootstrap to get the 95% CI for the quantity qtt.ci (which is the quantity for which I want to get the bootstrapped CI), but no success:**

```
library(bayesboot)

boot_fn <- function(dat) {
      coef.def <- unname(coef(glm(cbind(Pass, Fail) ~ A * B, binomial, dat)))
      qtt<- (exp(sum(coef.def[2:4])) - exp(coef.def[2]) - exp(coef.def[3]) + 1) 
      if(all(!is.na(qtt))) qtt else NULL
    }

Runs <- 1e2
qtt.ci <- bayesboot(dat, boot_fn, R = Runs, R2 = Runs)
summary(qtt.ci)

Quantiles:
 statistic    q2.5%     q25%   median     q75%   q97.5%
        V1 2.705878 2.705878 2.705878 2.705878 2.705878
```

Therefore, this does not give the CI for `qtt.ci`. The output is simply the point estimate for `qtt`:

```
qtt<-(exp(sum(coef.def[2:4])) - exp(coef.def[2]) - exp(coef.def[3]) + 1) 
qtt
[1] 2.705878
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where is the call to `bayesboot()`?

Comment: Just edited the question. Thanks @RuiBarradas.

Comment: Any solution @RuiBarradas?

Comment: Thanks, @MarcoSandri. Just edited. Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

The following solves the warning issue. I have tested it with much less runs, instead of 4000 just 100.

```
library(bayesboot)

boot_fn <- function(dat) {
  fit <- glm(cbind(Pass, Fail) ~ A * B, binomial, dat)
  coef.def <- unname(coef(fit))
  if(all(!is.na(coef.def))) coef.def else NULL
}

Runs <- 1e2
bb_ci <- bayesboot(dat, boot_fn, R = Runs, R2 = Runs)
summary(bb_ci)
```

**Edit.**

According to the formula in the question and the dialog in comments with the OP, to get the bootstrap-based CI run:

```
qtt <- exp(sum(bb_ci[2:4])) - exp(bb_ci[2]) - exp(bb_ci[3]) + 1
```

Comment: Great! Thanks @RuiBarradas. Actually my objective is to get the `bootstrap-based confidence interval` for the quantity `qtt.ci`. I have edited my question to emphasize this and added my attempt to get the `CI` for `qtt.ci` following your answer. Any idea?

Comment: I believe this has the values you want: `as.data.frame(summary(bb_ci))`.

Comment: `V4 = A:B`. That is not `qtt<-(exp(sum(coef.def[2:4])) - exp(coef.def[2]) - exp(coef.def[3]) + 1)`. The quantity for which I want to get the bootstrap-based CI is `qtt`, not `V4`. Any solution?

Comment: @Krantz OK, I think I've got it. In the formula for `qtt` you use `coef.def` but you don't have that value, you assign the return value of the function to `bb_ci`. Just substitute `bb_ci` for `coef-def`.

Comment: Not certain if I get your idea. Could you kindly edit you response?

Comment: @Krantz Is `qtt <- (exp(sum(bb_ci[2:4])) - exp(bb_ci[2]) - exp(bb_ci[3]) + 1)` what you want?

Comment: The quantity for which I want to get the bootstrap-based CI is `qtt <- (exp(sum(bb_ci[2:4])) - exp(bb_ci[2]) - exp(bb_ci[3]) + 1)`, yes.

Comment: Thanks @RuiBarradas.  But.ruunning `qtt <- exp(sum(bb_ci[2:4])) - exp(bb_ci[2]) - exp(bb_ci[3]) + 1` gives 3.806e+78, which is not correct.  The true CI for `qtt` is around 1.257277 to 4.356140. Any thoughts?